# what is this extra 'parse' call doing? (D3 time formatting)

Tags: d3.js

In this block,

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367

I see this

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;
```

which is used later like this

```
function type(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.price = +d.price;
  return d;
}
```

Why is `.parse` stuck on the end when every other example I've seen doesn't need it?

When I try to experiment with that syntax in other REPLs, I get a type error:

```
parseDate.parse is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It parses a string to a date.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#parse

In the context of `var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;`

`parseDate.parse is not a function` makes sense because `parseDate` is the function, not `parseDate.parse`. You call it like `parseDate('1/1/2016')`, not `parseDate.parse('1/1/2016')`

You don't need to stick `parse` at the end. 
You can do

`var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y")`

and then

`parseDate.parse('1/1/2015)`.

Example from D3 docs.

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
format.parse("2011-01-01"); // returns a Date
format(new Date(2011, 0, 1)); // returns a string
```

This allows you to format and parse a string. The first example only allows you to parse.

Comment: this describes the way things should normally work... but I was asking why the author DID stick parse at the end, yet it didn't throw a Type error.

Comment: OK, got it. It was throwing a Type error because I was calling .parse a SECOND time when I was parsing the date. Thanks